# How to have different icons for different Grafana alerting states in Slack?

Tags: grafana, alert, slack

I have configured Grafana to use Slack as the alert channel, and the alerts are correctly coming, except that all states have the same icon. I want Alerting, NoData and OK to have different icons and be more distinctive. Is this configurable?

The config in Grafana > Notifications settings > Optional Slack settings is not sufficient, as it's changing an icon globally, ie. for all states and all alerts in a Slack channel.

[image]